# Converting Asynchronous Code to Synchronous in Angular 6 - Return Type Constraint with Async/Await

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise, async-await, angular-promise

I was writing a service that would help fetch data from a URL, convert it into an array of type `returnType` and pass it on to whatever Component it got injected into:

**InjectableService** (`fetchJSON()` returns an `Observable<JSON>`):

```js
@Injectable(
  ...
)
export class InjectableService {
  dataToReturn: returnType[] = [];
  const url: string = "https://some.url/some.queries";

  constructor(private transactionService: TransactionService) {} //for encapsulating HTTP calls

  public getData(): returnType[] {
    this.transactionService.fetchJSON(this.url).subscribe(
      result => {
        this.functionToMassageResultIntoReturnTypeArray(result);
      }
    );

    return this.dataToReturn;
  }

  private functionToMassageResultIntoReturnypeArray(result: any) {
    //some logic...
    this.dataToReturn.push(//some data...);
  }
}
```

**ParentComponent** (Any changes to `this.data` reflects in the template):

```js
@Component(
  ...
)
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
  data: returnType[]= [];

  constructor(private dataService: InjectableService) {}

  ngOnInit {
    this.data = this.dataService.getData();
  }

  ngOnChanges {
    this.data = this.dataService.getData();
  }
}
```

Obviously, this failed because the subscription in `InjectableService.getData()`  does not resolve before the function returns the data. So, basically I needed a way to ensure that the asynchronous code in `InjectableService` (the `subscribe()` function) was executed in a synchronous manner.

Surprisingly enough, there's seems to be no simple way to do this in Angular 6. The closest I could find was the [`async-await`](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77) pattern:

```js
public async getData(): returnType[] {
  await this.transactionService.fetchJSON(this.url).subscribe(
    result => {
      this.functionToMassageResultIntoReturnTypeArray(result);
    }
  );

  return this.dataToReturn;
}
```

But this didn't compile - it was complaining about the function's return value; apparently, it can only return a 'Promise-compatible constructor value'.

Why would Angular constrain `async` functions to return Promise-like objects (which are inherently asynchronous), when the whole point of the `async-await` pattern is to make asynchronous code behave synchronously?

I have a feeling that there's a good reason behind this, but I'm missing the point here.

Comment: No, `async`/`await` does not make code synchronous. It lets you write asynchronous promise code in a synchronous manner, but an `async function` is inherently asynchronous and always returns a promise. This has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: `asynchronous promise code in a synchronous manner` - see that still implies synchrony to some (especially those who believe such majicks as synchronous asynchrony is even possible) .. I'd say *it looks synchronous* and add *(but isn't)* :p

Comment: @Bergi If an `async function` is still inherently asynchronous, then what exactly does `async/await` do? I'm confused as to what you mean by _"it lets you write asynchronous promise code in a **synchronous manner**"_...

Comment: @shinvu `await` is syntactic sugar for promise `.then()` callbacks. You're right, "synchronous manner" is misleading.